# What sql statement can I use in case null values appear?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables. I now want to create an overview in which I see all data of the first table, but instead of the InvoidId I want to see the InvoiceNumber (so 1->202101 and 2->202102).
I tried to do this with an INNER JOIN, but then I don't see the rows/sessions that don't have an InvoiceId.

It looks so easy, but I haven't figured it out yet. Can anyone help me? Thanx in advance!

Table 1: Session

| id | Description | Date | InvoiceId | Amount | ClientId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | Coaching | 10-09-2021 | 1 | 80,00 | 3 |
| 10 | Coaching | 17-09-2021 |  | 80,00 | 3 |
| 11 | Therapy | 12-09-2021 | 2 | 80,00 | 4 |
| 12 | Therapy | 19-09-2021 | 2 | 80,00 | 4 |

Table 2: Invoice

| Id | Date | Number | Amount | ClientId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11-09-2021 | 202101 | 80,00 | 3 |
| 2 | 22-09-2021 | 202102 | 160,00 | 4 |

Comment: What about a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN?

Comment: thnx dfundako! It works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a `left join`:

```
select s.*, i.number
from session s left join
     invoice i
     on s.invoiceid = i.id
```

Comment: Great..thnx Gordon!